# how to encode memorystream object to string in windows 8 using c#?

Tags: c#, .net

how to encode memorystream object to string in windows 8 using c#?

Code Snippet:

```
  DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);

            //return Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray()); //problem in this line
        }
```

Comment: What is the "problem"?

Comment: Use a StreamReader. And make sure to `ms.Position = 0;` first.

Answer (score 0):

read [Unicode and .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx) and use

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms); // or whatever encoding
return reader.ReadToEnd();
```